# Vim: Context sensitive code completion for PHP

Tags: php, vim

Vim gives me too much options when I use code completion.
In a class, and type $class-> it gives me about a zillion options, so not only from the class itself but also from php, all globals ever created, in short: a mess.

**I only want to have the options from the class itself (or the parent subtype class it extends from), so context or scope sensitive code completion, just like Netbeans for example. How can I do that?**

My current configuration is this:

I am using ctags, and created 1 ctags file for our (big) application in the root.

This is the .ctags file I used to create the ctags file:

```
-R
-h ".php"
--exclude=.svn
--languages=+PHP,-JavaScript
--tag-relative=yes
--regex-PHP=/abstract\s+class\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/interface\s+([^ ]+)/\1/c/
--regex-PHP=/(public\s+|static\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)\$([^ \t=]+)/\2/p/
--regex-PHP=/const\s+([^ \t=]+)/\1/d/
--regex-PHP=/final\s+(public\s+|static\s+|abstract\s+|protected\s+|private\s+)function\s+\&?\s*([^ (]+)/\2/f/
--PHP-kinds=+cdf
--fields=+iaS
```

This is the .vimrc file:

```
" autocomplete funcs and identifiers for languages
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#Complete

" exuberant ctags
" the magic is the ';' at end. it will make vim tags file search go up from current directory until it finds one.
set tags=projectrootdir/tags;
map <F8> :!ctags

" TagList
" :tag getUser => Jump to getUser method
" :tn (or tnext) => go to next search result
" :tp (or tprev) => to to previous search result
" :ts (or tselect) => List the current tags
" => Go back to last tag location
" +Left click => Go to definition of a method
" More info:
" http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html (official documentation)
" http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=94 (a vim tip)
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = "~/bin/ctags"
let Tlist_WinWidth = 50
map <F4> :TlistToggle<cr>

"see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE
" will change the 'completeopt' option so that Vim's popup menu doesn't select the first completion item, but rather just inserts the longest common text of all matches
:set completeopt=longest,menuone
" will change the behavior of the <Enter> key when the popup menu is visible. In that case the Enter key will simply select the highlighted menu item, just as <C-Y> does
:inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
"
inoremap <expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
  \ '<C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'

inoremap <expr> <M-,> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
  \ '<C-x><C-o><C-n><C-p><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the default PHPComplete, you have to generate your `tags` each time you do `$foo = new MyClass`. If you do that you'll get correct completion.

But there's another PHPComplete script that fixes this issue. You should [try it](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have tried phpcomplete, but still got a lot of options. Maybe I have php ftplugin not enabled. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: That script is to be put in `~/.vim/autoload/`. If the `~/.vimrc` in your question is *exactly* what you have on your machine, a very important piece is missing: `filetype plugin indent on`.

Comment: Put phpcomplet.vim in ~/.vim/autoload, and added "filetype plugin indent on" in ~/.vimrc, but still get all kinds of options...

Comment: Well, I don't know how to fix your situation. It works very well here.

Comment: With [this very basic setup](https://gist.github.com/3907584), `<c-x><C-o>` only proposes me `__construct(` and `publicMethod(` when I'm at the arrow.

Comment: I think the problem here is that Im using a very large code base (2 million lines). I will try your basic setup, thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm, did you consider using an IDE instead?

Comment: I am using Netbeans, but use vim if things go to slow. I know it *should* work correctly, just cannot get it done.

Comment: Did you manage to make my small setup work?

Comment: yes, that seems to work fine. It just does not work with big applications I guess. Although my problem still stands, I cannot mark this answer as accepted, but pls take the 50 pts as a thank you for your effort, especially since nobody else did.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately (?) I don't work on projects of that size so I can't help further.